# Can't import Numpy or any library (Anaconda Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

[image]

I am trying to import numpy, But I am getting an error like this(shown in the attached screenshot). Tried other Jupyter notebook and visual studio code, but getting the same error again and again.

There is no error while installing. But cant import

Comment: Did you install 32-bit anaconda on a 64-bit machine?

Comment: NO, I have checked before installing @Bill

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade numpy to v1.19.3:

```
pip install numpy==1.19.3
```

Please check out the [information page](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1207405/fmod-after-an-update-to-windows-2004-is-causing-a.html) as indicated by the error message. Go to the "Solutions" section at the end of the page, and you can see numerous people reporting this solution worked for them.

Answer (score -2):

Could be a dependency issue. Try creating a separate environment and install then import numpy there. Let me know if you have any questions!